# Build Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) for multiple targets

Tags: android, cross-platform, kernel-module

I'm the developer of an LKM for android.
Android runs on e.g. ARM, ARMv7, x-86 etc.

Currently, I'm building the kernel-module explicitly for

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS +=-march=armv7-a
$(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE... modules
```

and just insmod it on my phone.

But how should I do this for the mass?

I think I have to build the LKM with several configurations (ARCH=x-86 etc.) ?

I'm currently insmod-ing it automatically via an android-app - is it right, that I then have to determine the environment in my app and choose the right kernel-module for insmod ?

Thanks in advance for any help!